# ¿Como usar max height en un tbody?

Tags: css, css3

Estoy tratando de hacer que un `tbody` tenga una altura máxima y el contenido que tenga que se haga `scroll`, pero no termino de conseguirlo.

El problema es que al ponerle display block se me van todo el contenido del tbody al primer td y la idea es que mantenga el tamaño de las celdas y su lugar y que haga scroll solo en altura.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

He probado a meterle un `div` pero entonces se me va de paseo el contenido y no coincide con la posición de la tabla.

Aquí pongo un ejemplo funcional de como lo he hecho:

```css
.scroll {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="4"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="5"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="scroll">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Al darle `display:block` haces que se comporte como un `div` dentro de la tabla, por eso es que te lo pone todo en una columna, tendrías que agregar el atributo a toda la tabla

Comment: Pero si se lo aplico a toda la tabla se me suben las cabeceras tambien. la idea es dejarlas fijas @Yikarus

Comment: Para eso ya tendrías que meter código porque CSS no te permitirá hacer lo que quieres, la otra solución es que tus cabeceras sean otra tabla, o un elemento `div` con su respectiva configuración CSS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on Para que veas a lo que me refiero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución usando **solo `CSS` y con columnas de ancho fijo** podría ser esta:

```css
table.scroll {
  width: 522px; /* 100px * 5 columnas + 22px ancho scrollbar */
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead tr {
  display: block;
}

table.scroll tbody.wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

table.scroll tbody td,
table.scroll thead th {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

table.scroll thead th:last-child,
table.scroll tbody:not(.wrapper) td:last-child{
    width: 122px; /* 100px + 22px ancho scrollbar */
}

table.scroll tbody td input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
      <th>4</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="4"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="5"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="6"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody class="wrapper">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Referencia: [Respuesta relacionada SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17380697/3791844)

Comment: ¡¡Genial!! voy a intentar aplicarlo :)

Comment: No veo ningún max-height